# Use a resource dictionary as theme in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, themes, resources

I have developed an application which allows the user to switch between themes. I'm doing this by including the xaml file as a resource in my project and using the following code:

```
MainTheme.ThemeUri = new Uri("SilverlightApplication1;component/Themes/[ThemeName]/Theme.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

This worked well, untill I found these themes: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/05/17/silverlight-4-tools-released-and-new-application-templates.aspx

The difference is that these themes consist of multiple files. So I made a Theme.xaml file that only includes MergedDictionaries so I could still use the code above. This is the Theme.xaml file for the Cosmopolitan theme.

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="CoreStyles.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="SDKStyles.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ToolkitStyles.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

However, when I run the c# code above I get the following exception:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source'.
```

Just to be clear, using the MergedDictionaries method does work when I set it in my App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Cosmopolitan/Theme.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Setting absolute paths in my Theme.xaml file also doesn't work :(

Comment: I had a similar problem and the cause was using a backslash (\) instead of forward slash (/) when referencing the file.  The xaml parser in VS was able to resolve the location, but at run time an error was being generated. Hopefully this will help someone else out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you are using MergedDictionary you have to use fully qualified name like below.

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/SilverlightApplication1;component/Themes/Cosmopolitan/Theme.xaml"/>
```

Also, note that you should not miss the slash before the assembly name. In other words, it should be like

```
Source="/SilverlightApplication1;
```

not like

```
Source="SilverlightApplication1;
```

HTH

Comment: dont you have to put 'component' after the assembly name "/SilverlightApplication1;component/Themes/Cosmopolitan/Theme.xaml"

Comment: @Prince: The component part is essential. Please consider to update your answer. It will be a great answer after that update.